# Convert between C++20 NTTP and type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr, template-meta-programming

I'm playing around with C++20 NTTPs (non-type template parameters), and I was wondering, is there a way to convert between the elements of an NTTP `std::array` and types in the form of `T<int>`?

Consider this example:

```
template<int X>
struct Func;

template<auto ints>
struct Foo{

    // This doesn't work because within the std::apply the ints isn't a constant expression.
    constexpr auto funcs() const {
        return std::apply([](auto... xs){ return std::tuple{Func<xs>{}...};}, ints);
    }
};

constexpr Foo<std::array{1,2,3}> f;
constexpr auto funcs = f.funcs();
```

It easily works if the elements are values in a variadic NTTP pack, but having them in a `std::array` would allow to use the full power of the standard library algorithms rather than having to operate on parameter packs through TMP (template metaprogramming).

```
template<int... ints>
struct Foo2{

    // This here works, of course.
    constexpr auto funcs() const {
         return std::tuple{Func<ints>{}...};
    }
};

constexpr Foo2<1,2,3> f2;
constexpr auto funcs = f2.funcs();
```

Full code [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/j41KsWe6z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a parameter pack with indices to the `ints` array as template parameter pack using the `std::index_sequence` method:

```
return []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
    return std::tuple{Func<ints[I]>{}...};
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::size(ints)>{});
```

Then `ints[I]` can be used exactly as you intend `xs` to be used in your example.